# 14.04 login problem, are solutions affect the user file?

Tags: apt, sudo

Is this solution affect the user files?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

after I wrote that command, it needs the user password.

I did not proceed, because i'm afraid that this command affect
or erase the user file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not affect user files. It's simply asking password to do privileged task. Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` package.

However instead of that one liner, use these instead -

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install  ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I proceed to write the password, but an error occurred.

Comment: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: then do what was suggested

Comment: I try your suggested command

Comment: What usually the cause of these loop problem? is it possible in the hardware section?

Comment: That is hard to say, but most probably not. It's may be a result of mis-configuration

Comment: ahh I see, Thank for your response, it helps me a lot and solve my problem. Is there any way to thank you?

Comment: Glad to help. You have marked the answer as accepted I see. That works as "Thanks" :)